# Email : Cloud Pages URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Which is the correct way of generating Cloud Pages reference in the email message and pushing SubscriberKey as a parameter included in encrypted query string:

```
SET @unsub_url = RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(999, "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey))
```

OR

```
SET @unsub_url = CloudPagesURL(999, "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linking with CloudpagesURL automatically inserts the subscriberkey to the landingpage with the QS parameter that salesforce attaches (its hashed with more values but subscriberkey is in it).

The way to go would just be `RedirectTo(CloudpagesURL(999))`

To attach parameters that are not part of salesforce QS parameter it would be `Concat(RedirectTo(CloudpagesURL(999)),'&parametername=',@ampscriptvariable)` OR as Lukas Lunow already mentioned in the commend below `%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(999, 'parametername', @ampscriptvariable, 'parametername2', @ampscriptvariable2))=%%`. There should not be a difference between these functions/implementations (for me it was - but it could have been my mistake). [CloudpagesURL function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm)

Comment: why not just use CloudPagesURL function to pass *parametername*? E.g.: RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(999, 'parametername', @ampscriptvariable))

Comment: great comment, i recently had problems with this function and was altering my implementations to the above. I will integrate your addition into my answer.

Comment: Cheap 55 points :-P